# Ccannot implicitly convert type to System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

```
TS_Entities myent = new TS_Entities();
DEVICE_TRANSACTION dt = new DEVICE_TRANSACTION();

COSMETICALLY_TYPE ct = new COSMETICALLY_TYPE();
ct.ID = 1000008;
ct.NAME = "Ali";
dt.COSMETICALLY_TYPE = ct;
```

When i try to add cosmetically_type to DeviceTransaction i take this exception on "ct"

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'TeknikServis.COSMETICALLY_TYPE' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection'"

here is the below my edmx file 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship between the two looks like a many to many relationship.  It would need to be a 1 to 1 relationship for this to work the way you want it to.  Have you tried dt.COSMETICALLY_TYPE.Add(ct) ?  This is just assuming you want a many to many relationship.  The asterisks on the relationship line shows you the relationship.